# Recursive SQL query for finding matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have 5 SQL Tables with the following columns:

```
tbl_department:

department_id, parent_id


tbl_employee

employee_id, department_id


tbl_department_manager

department_id, employee_manager_id


tbl_request_regular_employee

request_id, employee_id


tbl_request_special_employee

request_id, employee_id
```

As input data I have `employee_id` and `request_id`.

I need to figure out whether the employee has access to the request (whether he's a manager or not)

We cannot use ORM here since app's responsiveness is our priority and the script might be called a lot.

Here's the logic I want to implement:

1. First we query to `tbl_department_manager` based on `employee_id` to check whether the current employee is a manager or not (also the employee can be a manager in a few departments). If so, we get a list of `department_id` (if nothing is found, just return false)
2. If we got at least one id in `tbl_department_manager` we query to `tbl_request_regular_employee` AND `tbl_request_special_employee` based on `request_id` and get `employee_id` from both tables (they are the same)
3. Based on `employee_id` collected above we query to `tbl_employee` to get a unique list of `department_id` that the employee belongs to.
4. Finally have a list of unique `department_id` from p.3 which we can compare to the one (ones) that we got in p.1.
5. The catch is, however, that in `tbl_department` there might be departments which inherit from the one (ones) that we got from p.1 (so we might need to find it recursively based on `parent_id` until we find at least one match with one element from p.1). If there's at least one match between one element in p.1 and one element in p.3 return true. So there's a need to look for it recursively.

Could someone give a clue how to implement it in MSSQL? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [so] isn't for asking for clues, it's for asking programming related questions. Instead show us what you've tried so far and explain why it isn't working. Provide us with consumable sample data, and expected results.

Comment: So is it a straight join between 1 and 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
declare @employee_id int, @request_id int;

with reqEmployees as (
    select regular_employee_id as employee_id
    from tbl_request_regular_employee
    where request_id = @request_id
  union all      --concatenate the two tables
    select special_employee_id
    from tbl_request_special_employee
    where request_id = @request_id
),
cte as (
    select e.department_id, null as parent_id
    from reqEmployees r
    join tbl_employee e  on e.employee_id = r.employee_id -- get these employees' departments
    union all
    select d.department_id, d.parent_id
    from cte              -- recurse the cte
    join tbl_department d on d.department_id = cte.parent_id   -- and get parent departments
)
-- we only want to know if there is any manager row, so exists is enough
select case when exists (select 1
    from cte   --join on managers
    join tbl_department_manager dm on dm.department_id = cte.department_id
    where dm.employee_manager_id = @employee_id)
  then 1 else 0 end;
```

Comment: Have modified it with these column names. You don't want to join like that, unless you want to ensure every `regular_employee_id` is also a `special_employee_id`, instead use `union` like I have shown. Or is there some other issue that I don't understand?

Comment: There are different id's names in `reqEmployees`. So, for table `tbl_request_regular_employee` there's `regular_employee_id` and for `tbl_request_special_employee` there's `special_employee_id` Could you please tell me how to join these 2 together in `join tbl_employee e  on e.employee_id = r.regular_employee_id OR  e.employee_id = r.special_employee_id` Apparently, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `regular_employee_id` and `special_employee_id` are totally equal, yet have different column names

Comment: Can you phrase precisely what logic you want, to check what `employee` is assigned to a request? I think what I gave you is good, if not please explain the exact logic you want. `regular_employee_id` and `special_employee_id` are both places where we can find an assigned employee, not necessatily will an employee be in both, is that correct?

Comment: Can you phrase precisely what logic you want, to check what `employee` is assigned to a request? - Yes

`regular_employee_id` and `special_employee_id` can be found in `tbl_employee` equally, there's no distinction between them, it's just poor database design

Comment: Meaning the two tables represent assigned employees but contain different `employee_id`s and we need to lookup both to find out if an employee is in *either* table, that's what I gave you already. Or are they identical and have *the same data*, so we only need to lookup one?

Comment: So with `select regular_employee_id as employee_id` and the union after, we can refer to both `regular_employee_id` and `special_employee_id` in `join tbl_employee e  on e.employee_id = r.employee_id` just by `r.employee_id`?

Comment: Correct, `reqEmployees` is now a kind of view that we can refer to, and has both tables unioned together, so any join will join on both tables. Remember that the optimizer will realize it only needs the first matching row, so it won't fully join the two tables first, just pick the first matching row from either.

Comment: Unfortunately, the query returns `The multi-part identifier “d.department_id” could not be bound` :(

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction. Could you please help me out with `No column name was specified for column 2 of "cte"`

Comment: Corrected that also, sorry I coded this without testing it because I didn't have DDL. You need to learn how to debug SQL. You should have seen where the missing name

Comment: It gave me `Column "parent_id" for "cte" is specified more than once` :(

Comment: Many thanks for giving me with the query, I truly appreciate your time and effort and I'm going to ask a separate question with more accurate info on tables, columns, etc